# Trying to understand my Python guessing game code

Tags: python, python-3.x

So as part of this Python I'm currently taking one of the exercises is to create a guessing game which run in the terminal. Obviously there are multiple ways of doing this and instead of simply watching the solutions video I tried to do it myself first. My code runs with no errors and as far as I can tell it should do the job, however it doesn't. Instead of just looking up a solution on here and rewriting the whole thing the just copies what someone else did I was wondering if someone could help me out with understanding why my code doesn't do what I expected it to?

It's listed below, thank you.

```
import random

digits = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(digits)
one = digits[0:1]
two = digits[1:2]
three = digits[2:3]

digits = one, two, three

guess = input("What is your guess? ")

g_one = guess[0:1]
g_two = guess[1:2]
g_three = guess[2:3]

while(guess != digits):
    print(digits)
    if(guess == digits):
        print("Congrats, you guessed correctly")
        break
    elif(g_one == one or g_two == two or g_three == three):
        print("One or more of the numbers is correct")
        guess = input("Try again: ")
    elif(g_one != one and g_two != two and g_three != three):
        print("None of those numbers are correct.")
        guess = input("Try again: ")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: What does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code. But how do you input "guess"?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I got it to give the result I was looking for, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not updating the values of g_one, g_two and g_three on every iteration.

```
digits = ([2], [3], [4]) # Assume this is the shuffling result, You are getting a tuple of lists here
guess = input("What is your guess? ") # 123
g_one = guess[0:1] #1
g_two = guess[1:2] #2
g_three = guess[2:3] #3

while(guess != digits): #123 != ([2], [3], [4]) string vs a tuple comparison here
  print(digits)
  if(guess == digits):
    print("Congrats, you guessed correctly")
    break
  elif(g_one == one or g_two == two or g_three == three):
    print("One or more of the numbers is correct")
    guess = input("Try again: ") #You are getting the input but the splits are not updated
  elif(g_one != one and g_two != two and g_three != three):
    print("None of those numbers are correct.")
    guess = input("Try again: ") #Same here. Not updating the splits
  else:
    break
```

I think that should explain it.

Comment: I've just changed it so it will update the user guesses (g_one, g_two, g_three). So now I also have to change so it isn't creating a tuple of lists but rather strings because strings are mutable? How should I go about doing that?

Comment: I suggest you use random.randint function for initialising and inputting numbers.
   `one = random.randint(0, 9) #same for the other two
    guess = int(input())`
You can get the digit places of the guess variable by modulo.

Comment: Ok, here is what I changed it to update and then make sure everything is an integer and it would tell me if the guess was wrong or if some of the numbers were correct but if I actually typed in the correct numbers it didn't register that. I then added something else and now I get a value error (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'p') My codes in the next comment

Comment: `import random

one = random.randint(0,9)
two = random.randint(0,9)
three = random.randint(0,9)

digits = one, two, three

guess = input("What is your guess? ")
guess = int(guess)

g_one = guess[0:1]
g_two = guess[1:2]
g_three = guess[2:3]

if(guess == digits):
 print("Congrats, you guessed correctly")`

Comment: `while(guess != digits):
 print(digits)
 if(g_one == one or g_two == two or g_three == three):
  print("One or more of the numbers is correct")
  guess = input("Try again: ")
  guess = int(guess)
  g_one = guess[0:1]
  g_two = guess[1:2]
  g_three = guess[2:3]
 elif(g_one != one and g_two != two and g_three != three):
  print("None of those numbers are correct.")
  guess = input("Try again: ")
  guess = int(guess)
  g_one = guess[0:1]
  g_two = guess[1:2]
  g_three = guess[2:3]
 else:
  break`

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad you figured that out